# how to use different meta tags in Larave React Application?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am working on a Laravel-ReactJS project and want to show different meta tags for different pages.
I have no idea how to do that, there are several packages but I don't know how to use them in Laravel-RreactJs applicaion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried react-helmet?

Answer (score 0):

Many React apps use react-helmet (and react-helmet-async) to manage their `<head>` tags, so Navi has special support for rendering your route title and head with the helmet. Setup is simple: just add the react-navi-helmet or react-navi-helmet-async package, and wrap your app with the exported HelmetProvider:

```
import HelmetProvider from 'react-navi-helmet-async'

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelmetProvider>
    <Router routes={routes}>
      ...
    </Router>
  </HelmetProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

With this, your `<View />` components will now know how to render their associated title and head properties. In fact, this will even work for static rendering using navi-scripts!